# pyodbc cursor's rollback functionality

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, informix

Using pyodbc I am updating three database tables. When updating the last table I am encountering an error and I am calling the rollback() function. The second table retains its updated values even on rollback(); first and third table are not updated as expected. Any reason why it is behaving this way?

```
dbCursor.execute("insert into table1(item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)

dbCursor.execute("update into table2(item21, item22, item23, item24, item25, item26) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)
---> two rows in the table get updated

dbCursor.execute("select item from table2 where unit_no = ?", unit_number)

tempVal = dbCursor.fetchone()

dbCursor.execute("update table3 set item31=?, item32=? where unit=?", val1, val2, tempVal)
---> Nothing gets updated as there is no tempVal found

if dbCursor.rowcount is 0:
    dbCursor.rollback()
```

Expected that rollback() will cause rollback on all the three tables, but table2 retains the value.

```
connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)  --> iclit09b.dll
connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER)   --> 4.10.FC4DE
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the values returned by `connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_NAME)` and `connection.getinfo(pyodbc.SQL_DRIVER_VER)`

Comment: Does the Informix database support transactions? Do you have auto commit turned off on your connection?

Comment: Presumably you mean `insert into table2` rather than `update into table2`?  The syntax is for an INSERT statement except that you have `update` instead of `insert`.

Comment: You have anonymized columns `itemNN` in the INSERT statements; you SELECT using `unit_number` which is not previously identified.  How are these tied together?  Why should the new data match the unit number?

Comment: maybe  AutoCommit set to true, which would mean that means every .execute you do will be committed. 
Try setting "autocommit(conn, 0)" before the first .execute. or set it to off in the connection string. More info here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection

Comment: @LuísMarques Yes, it supports transaction and auto commit is disabled. I am facing the issue in only one condition - when two rows gets updated in table 2. For one row I didn't face the issue. Entries in all three tables were rollback on error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, yes true. My code is something like dbCursor.execute("update table2 set suc_weight=?, suc_length=?, suc_height=?, suc_width=? where trade_unit_no = ?", cvsRowWeight, cvsRowLenght, cvsRowHeight, cvsRowWidth, cvsRowBarCode), for simplicity changed the column, values and table names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Values in INSERT statement are read from a file. unit_number is also read from a file. Sorry, I didn't mention all the details in my question. I will remember next time. unit_number is read from a file, but is also is one of the keys for table2. unit_no is the column name of the database table, unit_number is the temp variable where values read from a file is stored. I am trying to read values from a file and update existing entries in the database.

Comment: @jsagrera I have set the autocommit=False in my code.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test with 'autocommit = False' shows the rollback works as it should:

Create the test tables with:

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc# cat p.sql
drop table table1;
drop table table2;
drop table table3;
create table table1(item11 integer, item12 integer, item13 integer, item14 integer, item15 integer, item16 integer)     ;
create table table2(item11 integer, item12 integer, item13 integer, item14 integer, item15 integer, item16 integer)     ;
create table table3(item31 integer, item32 integer, item13 integer, unit integer, item15 integer, item16 integer)       ;
insert into  table2 values (1,1,1,1,1,1);
insert into  table2 values (1,1,1,1,1,1);

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc# dbaccess stores7 p
Database selected.
Table dropped.
Table dropped.
Table dropped.
Table created.
Table created.
Table created.
1 row(s) inserted.
1 row(s) inserted.
Database closed.
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc#
```

'table2' will have "1,1,1,1,1,1" for both rows

The python code below will output the data in 'table2', switch off AutoCommit and try the update.

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc# cat p.py 
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=irk1210')
dbCursor = cnxn.cursor()

value1          = "2"
value2          = "2"
unit_number     = "1"
val1            = "2"
val2            = "2"
tempVal         = "2"

print("before update")
dbCursor.execute("select item11,item12 from table2")
row = dbCursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)

#Set AutoCommit off
cnxn.autocommit = False

dbCursor.execute("insert into table1(item11, item12) values (?,?)", value1, value2)
dbCursor.execute("update table2 set item11=?, item12=?", value1, value2)

print("after update")
dbCursor.execute("select item11,item12 from table2")
row = dbCursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)

dbCursor.execute("select item11 from table2 where item12 = ?", unit_number)
tempVal = dbCursor.fetchone()
dbCursor.execute("update table3 set item31=?, item32=? where unit=?", val1, val2, tempVal)
if dbCursor.rowcount is 0:
    dbCursor.rollback()

print("after rollback")
dbCursor.execute("select item11,item12 from table2")
row = dbCursor.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)

informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc#
```

Output:

```
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc# python3 p.py 
before update
(1, 1)
after update
(2, 2)
after rollback
(1, 1)
informix@irk:/data/informix/IBM/OpenInformix/pyodbc#
```

The last select shows the update operation been rollback as expected. 
Values in the two rows are the same as before the update (1,1)

Comment: Thanks, rollback() worked for some table. I have rechecked the "SQL_TXN_CAPABLE" and it gives me the value of 2 .i.e SQL_TC_ALL = 2 - transactions can contain DML and DDL statements. Table 1 works as expected, table 2 has the problem, may be table 2 is different type of table (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0512.htm). Any idea how to check the type of the table?

Comment: umm. are you saying that you can rollback for table1 but not table2? Try to get the schema of the table (dbschema -d database -t table)